# Python: how to correctly convert from a string date in a particular time zone?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, python-dateutil

I have input from a human in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format that I know is supposed to be Los Angeles local time. In Python, how do I convert this to a `datetime.datetime` object that is unambiguous and correct? I am aware that the input is ambiguous during the autumn transition out of DST; I'm fine with either choice happening for dates within that hour as long as it is deterministic.

Here is my attempt, which I'm surprised to find doesn't work:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> from dateutil import parser as date_parser
>>> PACIFIC = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
>>> result = date_parser.parse('2016-08-01 00:00:00 FOO', tzinfos={'FOO': PACIFIC})
>>> result.utcoffset()
datetime.timedelta(-1, 57600)
>>> str(result)
'2016-08-01 00:00:00-08:00'
```

Despite having asked for `US/Pacific` and this being a summer date, I get UTC-8 instead of UTC-7.

Comment: The issue here is that `pytz` time zones cannot be easily attached like that. You need you use `PACIFIC.localize()` on the returned `datetime.datetime` object. Don't bother with `tzinfos` if you're using a single known time zone for all dates.

Comment: Oh, also, if you know the format of the date and the time zone, don't use `dateutil.parser`, it's inefficient and doesn't enforce the format (so mistakes in the format may still yield a date, but an incorrect one). Use `datetime.strptime`

Comment: Thanks @Paul; do you mind turning that into a worked example as an answer?

Comment: I can, but I'm out of the country at the moment so it might be a few days. I will not be offended if anyone else wants to take the idea and run with it. See [this page on documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/484/date-and-time#t=201609090138290125509) for existing worked examples.

Answer (score 0):

I found [This](https://artofsoftware.org/2012/04/17/dealing-with-daylight-savings-time-using-pytz/), which may help. Chopping it up a bit, I got the -0700 that you're looking for. I have to admit I don't understand this module, so I can't point to where you can fix your code quickly (and I don't use python on the command line much,) but the below works.

```
import datetime
import pytz

def report(time):
    mytz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
    dtformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
    t = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, dtformat).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
    print ("*****")
    print (t)
    print (mytz.normalize(t))

report("2011-08-01 00:00")
```

So, hope this helps!

Comment: This is helpful, but gives the wrong answer. The result of the last print statement is `2011-07-31 17:00:00-07:00`, but I'm looking for `2011-08-01 00:00:00-07:00`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dateparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dateparser) for that.

`import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse('2016-08-01 00:00:00', settings={'TIMEZONE': 'US/Pacific', 'TO_TIMEZONE': 'UTC'})
datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 1, 7, 0)`